# What does ?column? mean in the postgresql shell?

Tags: postgresql

When I run the following query in the psql shell, it prints `?column?` before the line that demarcates the response `t` (`=true`):

```
SELECT 'a fat cat sat on a mat and ate a fat rat'::tsvector @@ 'cat & rat'::tsquery;
?column?
----------
t
```

Why? What does this `?column?` bit mean?

Comment: It means that this column has no name. You can add one by using an `AS …` alias.

Comment: I see. I was confused because I didn't grasp that what was being drawn here was a table with one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?column?` is a default alias that PostgreSQL chooses as name for a column when it cannot find any other good name.

```
SELECT 42;
 ?column? 
----------
       42
(1 row)
```

Use an alias to choose a name of your liking:

```
SELECT 42 AS answer;
 answer 
--------
     42
(1 row)
```